# How to test ReactJS array of styles

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jestjs, enzyme

I have a component as below

```js
const TitleBreak = (props) => (
  <View style={[styles.container, props.style]}>
    <Text testID="title" style={styles.title}>
      {props.title}
    </Text>
  </View>
);
```

And I'm writing my test below

```js
  it('should render TitleBreak with backgroundColor: red', () => {
    const color = 'red';
    const titleBreak = shallow(
      <TitleBreak style={{ backgroundColor: color }} />,
    ).prop('style');

    expect(titleBreak).toHaveProperty('backgroundColor', color);
  });
```

And the above test has failed, due to array of styles. But I would like to test if `backgroundColor` has been overriden with red color, wondering how the test should be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe with `toContaineEqual({ backgroundColor: 'red' })`?

https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#tocontainequalitem

> Use .toContainEqual when you want to check that an item with a specific structure and values is contained in an array. For testing the items in the array, this matcher recursively checks the equality of all fields, rather than checking for object identity.

```js
it('should render TitleBreak with backgroundColor: red', () => {
  const style = { backgroundColor: 'red' };
  const titleBreak = shallow(<TitleBreak style={style} />,).prop('style');
  expect(titleBreak).toContaineEqual(style);
});
```